# System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden when access Google API

Tags: c#, asp.net, c, api, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the Google API on my website. It works
fine from my localhost, but on the live server I get the following
error:

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403)
Forbidden.
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at GoogleUrlShortnerApi.Shorten(String url)
```

I'm using the code found here:
http://www.thecyberwizard.com/index.php/5/google-analytics-api-in-c-part-1/

And from debugging, I see that the error occurs on the

```
HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();
```

command.

Does anyone know what could be causing the error (again, the error
happens only on the server. When I run this code locally on my
computer, it runs fine and retrieves a short url).

I have to turn off billing still I get the following
error:

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403)
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

It's working by changing the _autoPostData value to `"â?accountType=HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE&Email={0}&Passwd={1}&service=analytics&source=thecyberwizard.comâ"`.